# Flatten a list in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's assume my list is like this:

```
List<List<string>> zz = new List<List<string>>() { new List<string>{"1","2","3"}, new List<string> { "4", "5", "6" } };
```

I want one list as output as follows:

```
List<string> finalList = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4", "5", "6"};
```

**How do I flatten to this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var finalList = zz.SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var finalList = zz.SelectMany(x=>x).ToList();
```